# React material-table and redux dev tools

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am learning to React development. I build an application using react and redux. Recently I have added material-ui and material-table into my project and it seems that material-table is overriding my redux actions and states in Redux DevTools. The application it selves is working fine. The problem is just with Redux DecTools. I tried to google it but without success. Thanks for any hints or directions.

[When i use material-table i can see this in Redux devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDNLu.png)

[In case i use MUIDataTable instead i can see my redux states](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlUio.png)
Čau
Honza

Answer (score 2):

Yes, material-table mutates the data by adding a `tableData` object it.

Its a long known problem, but the author does not want to change it yet.

The best way to handle it, is to make a shallow copy of your data before passing it to the table to prevent the mutation of the redux data:

```
const tableData = data.map(row => ({...row}));
```

And wrap that in a useState/useEffect to only execute it, if data changes.

[PR](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/pull/1174) and [Discussion](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/1371)

Comment: thank you for the answer but it didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Can you share you code so I can see what's going on?

Comment: i tried to make it as simple as possible so i removed all data from table and still it overrides the state in redux dev tools. The only states i can see when i use the material-table is: phase(pin):"IDLE"
completed(pin):null
shouldFlush(pin):false

Comment: i have just put here the whole material-table component in very basic form. When i use this component it overrides my redux data.

Comment: That should not affect your dev tools at all. Can you show us what happens. maybe with a screenshot

Comment: i have added printscreens. I tried to use MUIDataTable instead and it works fine however i would like to understand what is wrong with material-table.

Comment: Did you try selecting a redux instance as written on the top of your screen shot? I think its connected to react-hot-loader, which might interfere with the selection.

Comment: Bingo! It is there. I can see there three instances, all of them are called React app. When i select the first one i can see my data. Do you know what are the others about?

Answer (score 0):

This is my material-table component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import MaterialTable from "material-table";

import { forwardRef } from 'react';

import AddBox from '@material-ui/icons/AddBox';
import ArrowDownward from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowDownward';
import Check from '@material-ui/icons/Check';
import ChevronLeft from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRight from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import Clear from '@material-ui/icons/Clear';
import DeleteOutline from '@material-ui/icons/DeleteOutline';
import Edit from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import FilterList from '@material-ui/icons/FilterList';
import FirstPage from '@material-ui/icons/FirstPage';
import LastPage from '@material-ui/icons/LastPage';
import Remove from '@material-ui/icons/Remove';
import SaveAlt from '@material-ui/icons/SaveAlt';
import Search from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import ViewColumn from '@material-ui/icons/ViewColumn';

const tableIcons = {
    Add: forwardRef((props, ref) => <AddBox {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Check: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Check {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Clear: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Delete: forwardRef((props, ref) => <DeleteOutline {...props} ref={ref} />),
    DetailPanel: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Edit: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Edit {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Export: forwardRef((props, ref) => <SaveAlt {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Filter: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FilterList {...props} ref={ref} />),
    FirstPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FirstPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
    LastPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <LastPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
    NextPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
    PreviousPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronLeft {...props} ref={ref} />),
    ResetSearch: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Search: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Search {...props} ref={ref} />),
    SortArrow: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ArrowDownward {...props} ref={ref} />),
    ThirdStateCheck: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Remove {...props} ref={ref} />),
    ViewColumn: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ViewColumn {...props} ref={ref} />)
  };

const MyTable = () => {

    return (
        <div style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}>
        <MaterialTable   icons={tableIcons}     
          columns={[

            { title: "Department", field: "department" },
            { title: "Name", field: "name" },
            { title: "Status", field: "status" },
            { title: "Start Date", field: "startDate", type: "date" },

          ]}
          data={[]}
          title="Demo Title"
        />
      </div>
    )

}

export default MyTable;
```

Comment: You should update your question istead of posting an answer. Can you share a picture of your dev tools

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to see your states. You can view your states by navigating to it with the dropdown menu on the top right corner, where it says "Autoselect instances".